# How can i set the title of my push notification in my php script?

Tags: php, android, push-notification

This is my php script and I am sending the body and the title strings from my android app .Here I'm able to get the message body in my notification but not the title and even if I put;
        `$message = array(
        'message' => $body,
        'title'   => 'This is my title',
        'sound'   => 1
    );`

This is also not working.

```
<?php 
$body = $_POST["body"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$inc_phone = $_POST["inc_phone"];

function send_notification ($tokens,$message)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $tokens,
         'data' => $message
        );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = AIzaSyAe9Qxx2URTyqXmf0mTheMq_ss_DOJaVQs ',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);           
   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}
//Connect to the database
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$user = "rajhanssingh";                     //Your Cloud 9 username
$pass = "";                                  //Remember, there is NO password by default!
$db = "fcm";                                  //Your database name you want to connect to
$port = 3306;                                //The port #. It is always 3306

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db, $port);

//$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fcm");
$sql = " Select token From utoken where phone_no='$inc_phone' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$tokens = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tokens[] = $row["token"];
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
$message = array(
    'message' => $body,
    'title'   => $title,
    'sound'   => 1
);
$message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
echo $message_status;
?>
```

Comment: Hi, Tarun. Could you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
function send_push_notification($registrationIDs, $message) {

     $GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyCzr6K_W3ImYwVQ-vQyhFztDSmchkFjeGQ";

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
        'data' => ['message' => $message, 'title' => 'Title' ]
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );




    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
  //  echo $result;
}
```